# MySQL setup: The memory could not be written

Tags: mysql, memory-management

I am using Windows 7 Professional and my configuration is:

Processor: i3.
RAM: 8GB.
Arch: 64 bit.

When I am installing MySQL server on my system getting following error

> "The instruction at 0x6d7724ff referenced memory at 0x6d7724ff. The memory could not be written"

I have tried all possible solutions like- driver update, page memory, different version of MySQL server etc.